# Do we still do 'general' questions comparing technology?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Well - at some point in future, budget allowing, I'd be looking at getting new monitors. When I got my current one, It was basically TN and IPS in my size range. Since then there's a lot more variation, with 'Desktop' sized OLEDs, MiniLEDs, quantum dots and so on. And while display technology does go extinct (I can't see myself finding a new plasma or CRT in 2023), the general landscape of options ought to be relevant short of us getting real free space holograms.

Back in the day - I'd asked about [reopening a question on keyboards](https://superuser.com/questions/366221/differences-between-cherry-mechanical-keyboard-switches), which resulted in large edits, and ended up being a (still relevant) resource today

I do realise that things have changed a lot since - so I'm wondering, would a similar question, asking about differences in PC monitor panel types be relevant/acceptable to the scope and community standards of today?

In general, what *should* be the boundaries of such a question if its asked today?

Comment: I'm wondering if Hardware Recommendations still exists... It does [hardwarerecs.se] It still shows "beta"

Comment: Oh - if I wanted a *specific* recommendation for model, certainly. This is more of things like stuff like IPS vs IPS black vs VA vs QLED vs. QOLED vs OLED vs.... and that's not counting things like local dimming... different refresh rates...

Comment: Related [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/289691)

Comment: I think sometimes it's how fast you can run in front of the down & close voters, who can get pretty quick on the draw on SU. Ask Different puts up with this type of question if it could be labelled 'canonical'. On AD Meta there's a maintained list of canonical QAs, pointing to all these. Many are maintained, sporadically, by but a few. Some start from a general OP question that later gets fleshed out. The brave go all-in with a self-answer… that they then become honour-bound to maintain. How brave are you feeling?

Comment: This stack has traffic too… Hardware Recs doesn't. Are you planning to release the next James Cameron to cinemas worldwide, or play shadow puppets in your living room for the kids & neighbours? ;) Getting it in here gets it an audience. I know you don't need the rep, but a good canonical is a good canonical for time to come. I have a couple that actually took little effort & little maintenance generating views all the time, & 1200 or so votes; another that I do have to actively maintain with 1/10th of that interest, but of equal if not greater usefulness.

Comment: Well - the specific question I'm thinking of is very much not a "what to buy" - so hardware recs is not the right space. Its also kinda broad - I could have gotten away with it in the early days, but I'm trying to figure out the best approach to getting information on say OLED vs Mini/micro Leds vs local dimming vs the old VA/IPS/TN decision.... not to mention the quantum versions of each.

Comment: @Tetsujin with 100+K rep and a diamond.... probably very. I do want to do it right though, and I'm in no *particular* rush

Comment: Personally, I feel it could be the type of QA that adds value to the site - but getting it right without raising the ire of the fly-by dv/cv crowd is going to be the stumbling block on here. AD does tend towards more tolerance of borderline on-topic generally, if there's value.